# How to use XARGS to copy file list from CSV or TEXT file?

Tags: csv, terminal, xargs

I'm trying to copy images based on csv/txt file using xargs, unfortunately it can only copy the last line of csv/txt file.

Running on macOS

**FOLDER CONTENT:**
images(folder)
img_1.jpg
img_2.jpg
img_3.jpg
img_4.jpg
img_5.jpg
file.csv
file.txt

**file.csv CONTENT:**
img_1.jpg
img_2.jpg
img_3.jpg

**file.txt CONTENT:**
img_1.jpg
img_2.jpg
img_3.jpg

**Already tried:**
`$ cat file.csv | xargs -t -I [] find . -type f -name "[]*"  -exec cp {} images/ \;`
`$ cat file.csv | xargs -t -I % cp % images/`

`$ cat file.csv | xargs -t -I % sh -c 'find . -type f -name %; cp % images/'`

**GOAL:**
Copy only image_1.jpg, image_2.jpg & image_3.jpg to images folder

**CODE 1 OUTPUT:**
`$ cat file.csv | xargs -t -I [] find . -type f -name "[]*"  -exec cp {} images/ \;`

`* -exec cp {} images/ ;img_1.jpg
* -exec cp {} images/ ;img_2.jpg
find . -type f -name img_3.jpg* -exec cp {} images/ ;
cp: images/img_3.jpg and ./images/img_3.jpg are identical (not copied).`

*NOTE: Only image_3.jpg has been copied to images folder*

---

**CODE 2 OUTPUT:**
`$ cat file.csv | xargs -t -I % cp % images/`

`images/img_1.jpg
cp:  img_1.jpg\r: No such file or directory
 images/img_2.jpg
cp: img_2.jpg\r: No such file or directory
cp img_3.jpg images/`

*NOTE: Again, only image_3.jpg has been copied*

---

**CODE 3 OUTPUT:**
`$ cat file.csv | xargs -t -I % sh -c 'find . -type f -name %; cp % images/'`

`images/img_1.img_1.jpg
cp: img_1.jpg\r: No such file or directory
 images/img_2.jpg img_2.jpg
cp: img_2.jpg\r: No such file or directory
sh -c find . -type f -name img_3.jpg; cp img_3.jpg images/
./img_3.jpg
./images/img_3.jpg`

*NOTE: Again, only image_3.jpg has been copied*

Comment: See [these](https://superuser.com/q/180251/473637) [posts](https://serverfault.com/q/212439/343635).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `file.csv` seems to have `\r\n` end of lines ("text" format from non-Unix/Linux OS-es), also if `file.csv` has the correct files' path (current directory afaics) then there's no need for `find`.
Removing the `\r` should be enough to make it work (e.g. via `tr`):

```
cat file.csv | tr -d '\r' | xargs -t -I % cp -pvf % images/
```